# Struts2/Hibernate/Spring project with multiple ehcache cacheManager

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi my project is Struts2/Hibernate/Spring.
With the following versions:

1. Hibernate 5.2.5.Final
2. Struts2 2.3.31
3. Spring 4.3.5.RELEASE
4. ehCache 2.10.3

We are using annotations-based configuration. And we have the following ehCache class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

@Bean
public EhCacheCacheManager cacheManager() {
    return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheCacheManager().getObject());
}

@Bean
public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheCacheManager() {
    EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cmfb = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
    cmfb.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
    cmfb.setShared(true);
    cmfb.setAcceptExisting(true);
    return cmfb;
}
```

}

We have a main method that is called via Quartz cron job:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com.abc");
    MyJobUtil myJob = new MyJobUtil(context);

    ...our business logic code...

    myJob.destroy(context);
}
```

The problem is, when the main method is fired up the Quartz cron job, we run in the following error:

```
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another CacheManager with same name 'oddsCache' already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name.
```

We have searched the forum and set the EhCacheManagerFactoryBean to share = true, yet this is happening. Any suggestions/ideas to resolve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change `new CacheManager(Configuration configuration)` to `CacheManager.newInstance(Configuration configuration)` in your cacheManager() method. Please refer [CacheManager Creation Modes](http://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.9.0/html/ehc-all/#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fco-key_cachemanager.html%23)